# insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost

Tags: web3js, gas, javascript, ethers.js, failed-transaction

i've codded a script using js to trigger a buy on uniswap.
the way i achieved this is through importing uniswaps smart contracts using this line of code:

```
const router = new ethers.Contract(addresses.router,['function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
```

],

in any case unfortunately I was met with an error saying unable to estimate gas limit , and after setting proper parameters for 'gasPrice' and 'value'
I receive this error:

> Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost (error={"code":-32000,"response":"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":4,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for transfer"}}"}, method="estimateGas"

this is the code i used for my Uniswap Trade:

```
async function Buythis(){
const token0 = addresses.WETH; //Etherium
const token1 = '0x358aa737e033f34df7c54306960a38d09aabd523' //Desired Coin Address
const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.1', 'ether'); //Amount you wish to buy with. (0.15 eth in wallet currently.)
console.log('Amount in Passed')
const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [token0, token1]);
console.log('Amounts out calculated')
const amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(5)); //slippage
console.log('Slippage is set.')
var options = {gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('50', 'gwei'), value: ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.04', 'ether')};
console.log('Initiating Order.')
const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(
  amountOutMin, 
  [token0, token1], 
  addresses.recipient, 
  Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10,
  options
  );
```

EDIT : yes it logged 'Initiating order' so the error is in the swapExactETHforTokens

Answer (score 9):

The wallet that you connected to your `router` contract object does not have enough ETH balance to cover `value + gasPrice * gasLimit`.

In your case `value = 0.04 ETH`.

Assuming gasLimit = 200,000, `gasPrice * gasLimit = 200000 * 50 * 10^-9 = 0.01`.

So total you need to have at least `0.05 ETH` balance (based on estimated gasLimit as above).

Answer (score 4):

For me, the error came up because I was deploying my contract with an eth value greater than what I had in my Metamask wallet.

My total wallet balance was 0.9 ETH and I was trying to deploy with 1ETH :

`var contract = await contractFactory.deploy({value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1")});`

changing the value to 0.07 solved it:

`var contract = await contractFactory.deploy({value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("0.07")});`

Answer (score 1):

I also had parseEther at ("1") and increased the amount of ETH in my wallet to above 1 using the goerli faucet.

This fixed the problem for me.

my code: `const sendValue = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")`

You could also fix this by decreasing that amount like the above answer.

Link to faucet: https://goerlifaucet.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was testing a revert scenario and ethers couldnt estimate the gas properly because it knew the operation would fail. More [here](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/troubleshooting/errors/#help-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT).

Just putting the asLimit manually didnt work, I had to include the `maxFeePerGas`, and the `maxPriorityFeePerGas`as well like this:

```
const feeData = await ethers.provider.getFeeData();
await contract.funtion(arguments, {gasLimit: 250000, maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 0.1TBNB in the sender and receiver wallet. I set a minimum gas price is 21000 in the transaction parameters as below. I got the "insufficient balance error". Can you please suggest? stack overflow unable to help on my request.

```
const createTransaction =  await object.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
     {
        from: addressFrom,
        to: addressTo,
        value: object.utils.toHex(object.utils.toWei("0.00001", "ether")),
        gasPrice: await object.eth.getGasPrice()
     },
     privKey
  );

  // Deploy transaction
  const createReceipt = await object.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
     createTransaction.rawTransaction
  );`
```

I got the below error.

```
     innerError: { code: -32000, message: 'insufficient funds for transfer' }, 
  code: 101,
  data: undefined,
  request: {
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    id: 'b4e14330-e710-4ace-934e-f27624214872',
    method: 'eth_estimateGas',
    params: [
      {
        from: '0x33De79D574B096397492c163Df18CCE737b49990',
        to: '0x15878f0A35F006864f8d480537C07630db6f48c8',
        value: '0x3130303030303030303030303030',
        gasPrice: '0x2540be400',
        nonce: '0x0',
        input: '0x',
        chain: 'mainnet',
        hardfork: 'london',
        chainId: '0x61',
        networkId: '0x61',
        type: '0x0'
      },
      'latest'
       ]
```

Comment: This is a question not an answer. Also convert the value you are sending, it is "997655935916089812264981854433328". Maybe look at what is happening when you set that.

Comment: Hi, Sorry. can you please explain more.

Comment: This "value: '0x3130303030303030303030303030',"
when converted from hexadecimal to integer is 997655935916089812264981854433328. Which converted from wei, would be 997655935916089.812264981854433328 tBNB